# Detecting Modal MailItem Creation in Outlook from Windows Context Menu via VSTO Add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm developing a VSTO Add-in for Outlook using C#. In a scenario where a user selects "Send to -> Mail recipient" from the right-click context menu in Windows Explorer, Outlook is invoked, and a new MailItem opens in a modal window.

My objective is to identify within the add-in when the MailItem is created from this specific action, as opposed to other ways of creating a MailItem. This is important because the behavior of my add-in depends on the origin of the MailItem creation.

Is there a way to determine programmatically in the C# VSTO add-in if a MailItem is opened in a modal window as a result of the "Send to -> Mail recipient" action? If so, how can I implement this detection?

I understand that the Outlook Inspector window does not directly expose a property to check for modality. Are there any indirect methods or properties that could reliably indicate the modal state of a MailItem or its creation context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is to take advantage of the fact that `Inspectors.NewInspector` event does not fire for messages opened through Simple MAPI even though the `Inspectors` collection (`Count` etc.) lists these inspectors: keep track of `Inspectors.NewInspector` and `Inspector.Close` events to keep your own tally of the inspectors count. If you are off, you can assume the inspector was opened through Simple MAPI.

Comment: For an obscure reason, it's look like my NewInspector event no more Trigger. 

this.Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += Inspectors_NewInspector; and nothing happen on new email. That weird. The event is register in the startup event, and other events are also register and work. I will need to figure out if Microsoft change something on theire side.

Comment: You need to keep `Inspectors` object in a dedicated variable on the class level - your code above causes C# compiler to create a temporary implicit variable, which gets released by the Garbage Collector.

Comment: Got it, thank for the tips. The Applications was in a variable but not the Inspectors. Thanks i will try that.

Comment: Thank you, i beleive that strategie work well.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model (or VSTO) doesn't provide anything for that out of the box.

If Outlook was not not running prior to using the context menu (`SendTo`) you can check out whether any Explorer window exists (`Explorers.Count`) and visible. Typically in such scenarios you deal only with an inspector window opened.

Also under scenario described you may not get some events, so keeping the sequence of events allows you to distinguish between the regular usage and the `SendTo` one.

Comment: But in that case, correct me if i am wrong, but if for example Outlook is already open when the rightclick is done, then the Explorers.Count could have some counts ?

Comment: Yes, you should always have the explorer window opened in that case.